# Prevent Multiple Postings using REFRESH

Tags: jsp, servlets

Here is the scenario my form posts data to a servlet which in return makes changes to a db and attaches an object to the request attribute and forwards to a JSP page.

Now the problem is if the refresh button on the JSP is clicked , the process loops back and since it was a forward the servlet re-enters the data. I could actually solve this problem by redirection instead of forwarding from the servlet to the jsp page and attaching the object as an attribute to the session instead of request.

But i wanted to know if there was a better way to do this ?

I dont want to store everything i come across in session and is there a way to know if this was a refresh event ?

Answer (score 0):

Data can be posted using `GET or POST`. If `GET` method is refreshed, `which is idempotent`, the `browser automatically makes request to the server` .

But, if the method was `POST`, `which is non-idempotent`, `the browser will raise a popup asking the user to really post the data and this may repeat the operation again`.

If you are using GET, then i would suggest to change it to POST.

**But the best solution is POST + REDIRECT + GET.**